# Handle Microsoft authentication response when application can not be accessed externally

Tags: python, django, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/python) to build a Python Django app that uses Microsoft Graph.
I need to authenticate with Azure AD to do that and I have already set up an app registration.

The problem is that I'm under a company network that does not permit access from external sources and because of that the Redirect URI used when returning authentication responses (tokens) after successfully authenticating users can not be reached.

How can I get the authentication token in that case? Is the callback URL really necessary?

Comment: I am exactly at the same situation as you, as a workarrount i have used the django alauth office 365 app https://github.com/Lamelos/django-allauth-office365

Comment: Uhmm I will check if that works, thanks.

Comment: Just tell me if you encounter an issue as i have faced many issues to getting it work finally

Comment: Well, that solution still needs a callback URL that can not be accessed in my case. So, no luck.

Comment: Your app is deployed on a server ?

Comment: No, I'm just running it from my computer.

Comment: okey can you try to install the app and just add this callback url on the azure application http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/office365/login/callback/

Comment: It won't work as the tutorial does not create an `accounts` path.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that you have to use the django allauth identification system so you will have automatically the accounts path, here a tutorial https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually a missing proxy configuration in Django.
I added the following lines to the file `wgsi.py` and everything worked:

```
import os

os.environ['http_proxy'] = 'http://my.proxy.url:8080'
os.environ['https_proxy'] = 'http://my.proxy.url:8080'
```